# SSRS - Webservice - DataSet - Cannot read the next data row for the dataset

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am trying to use SSRS 2010 webservices to call an existing report, in html format, to embed in another web page.

The report I am calling depends on a parameter and 3 other datasets embedded in the report.

**When I call the report in a browser the reports works perfectly.**

But when i call the report using the webservice, sending the only parameter required I am getting the error message:

"Cannot read the next data row for the dataset MembershipRegistrationPayments."

I am confused because the report works perfectly in a browser and the only "selection" needed to make the report run is "Club ID".

Here is the code i have so far...

```
ReportExecutionService rsExec = new ReportExecutionService();

rsExec.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usernamexxx", "passwordxxx", "domainxxx");

string report = "/DemoReport1";
bool forRendering = false;
string historyID = null;
string format = "MHTML";
string extension;
string mimeType;
string encoding;
string deviceInfo = null;
ReportExecution.Warning[] warnings;
string[] streamIDs;

ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();

rsExec.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;

execInfo = rsExec.LoadReport(report, historyID);

var execParameters = new List<ReportExecution.ParameterValue>();
execParameters.Add(new ReportExecution.ParameterValue() { Name = "OrganisationID", Value = "1234" });

rsExec.SetExecutionParameters(execParameters.ToArray(), "en-GB");

byte[] reportBytes = rsExec.Render(
format,
deviceInfo,
out extension,
out mimeType,
out encoding,
out warnings,
out streamIDs);
```

It's almost as of the datasets are not being called when the report is generated and thus the it cannot move to the first record in the dataset?

I'm lost. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Trev

Comment: I had this exact error today but it gave more information after the 'cannot get next data row' message. I think it was a type casting issue. My suspicion is that the only thing different is the parameter value but it may not be obvious from the code. Are you able to capture the GET that is sent to the web server and inspect the URL that is being used (if that's the way it works). Can you temporarily set the parameter to optional and call it without a parameter and see if that helps?

Comment: i think you might be on the right lines. I see the error "The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.Cannot read the next data row for the dataset MembershipRegistrationPayments."

Comment: That's the exact error I got today but I for the life of me I cannot recall the solution! You could try capturing the SQL in Profiler and see of that gives any clues.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the SQL in the report itself, not your code.

Comment: @Nathan i think it's either a server or report problem as I am not even sending a parameter including any date... the report has "date" parameters but they are all set to "get values from a query"

Comment: The report could have multiple datasets in it and there could be comparisons between incompatible types in the SQL for any of them, or possibly the "Date" parameters have the wrong datatype (parameter is nvarchar and the parameter query is returning dates or vice versa)

Comment: yes, correct, the report does have multiple datasets all set to "Use a dataset embedded in my report" with a query type of "Text" - i dont understand how the report works from /reportviewer.aspx but not via the asmx webservice?

Comment: @ElectricLlama did you manage to remember what you did? I am still stuck :(

Comment: Did you get a chance to capture the SQL In Profiler? All will be revealed there. That's what I did to solve my problem.

Comment: @ElectricLlama the problem I have is that the report server is on a client server which I cannot get access to :(

Comment: To use Profiler you just need to be able to connect to the database - can you do that? If not.... you'll just have to divide and conquer - enable only one dataset at a time until you find the dataset causing the issue. Then disable bits of that until you narrow it down.

Comment: last night I managed to find time to build my own reportserver and a report based on a SQL dataset. it all works perfectly. admittedly it was based on a different data source, running of a different server, but, it did have multiple datasets and datetime parameters... the search continues...

Comment: Which RDL file contents ? How you send reportBytes  to browser ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phew! Finally fixed it!

Background:

I have a Dataset that creates a number of fixed dates that are used in another Dataset.

As an example, this is what 1 of the SQL statements ORIGINALLY looked like that generate that date..

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN getdate() >= DATEADD(Day, 0, DATEADD(Month, 3, DATEADD(Year, DATEDIFF(Year, 0, getdate()), 0))) THEN DATEADD(Day, 0, DATEADD(Month, 3, DATEADD(Year, DATEDIFF(Year, 0, getdate()), 0)))
WHEN getdate() <= DATEADD(Day, 0, DATEADD(Month, 3, DATEADD(Year, DATEDIFF(Year, 0, getdate()), 0))) THEN DATEADD(Year, - 1, DATEADD(Day, 0, DATEADD(Month, 3, DATEADD(Year, DATEDIFF(Year, 0, getdate()), 0))))
END AS StartDate
```

I have fixed the problem by converting the date result to a varchar in the SQL statement so that the reporting server no longer tries to do it "internally"

So, my SQL now looks like this:

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN getdate() >= DATEADD(Day, 0, DATEADD(Month, 3, DATEADD(Year, DATEDIFF(Year, 0, getdate()), 0))) THEN CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(Day, 0, DATEADD(Month, 3, DATEADD(Year, DATEDIFF(Year, 0, getdate()), 0))) ,113)
WHEN getdate() <= DATEADD(Day, 0, DATEADD(Month, 3, DATEADD(Year, DATEDIFF(Year, 0, getdate()), 0))) THEN CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(Year, - 1, DATEADD(Day, 0, DATEADD(Month, 3, DATEADD(Year, DATEDIFF(Year, 0, getdate()), 0)))) ,113)
END AS StartDate
```

And now the report works perfectly!